# proof that a set is functionally complete

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

Consider the following operators: [(they are in the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoNV.png)

a) is {∼,→} functionally complete? Demostrate.

b) is {+,→} functionally complete? Demostrate.

I think that both sets are not functionally complete, but i dont know how to prove. I know that for induction is a good idea, but is difficult. Help plz

Comment: Note to onlookers who don't feel like clicking the link and might be misled by the notation: ~ is not negation and + is not "or". They the unary operators ~A=0 and +A=1.